# Contract.Ensures unproven in Multiple object / class chain Code Contracts

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have the following class structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace contractsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IService s = new Service();
            s.sendMessage(MessagesCreator.TestMessage);
        }
    }

    class Service : IService
    {
        public void DoSomething(Message m)
        {
        }
    }

    static class MessageNames
    {
        public static string TestMessage
        {
            get
            {
                Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Contract.Result<string>()));
                return "TestMessage";
            }
        }
    }

    class Message
    {
        public Message(string _name)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name));
            Contract.Ensures(this.Name == _name);
            this.Name = _name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    static class MessagesCreator
    {
        public static Message TestMessage
        {
            get
            {
                Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Message>() != null);
                Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Message>().Name == MessageNames.TestMessage);

                return new Message(MessageNames.TestMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void sendMessage(this IService service, Message m)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(service != null);
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(m != null);
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Name));

            service.DoSomething(m);
        }
    }

    [ContractClass(typeof(IServiceContract))]
    interface IService
    {
        void DoSomething(Message m);
    }
    [ContractClassFor(typeof(IService))]
    abstract class IServiceContract : IService
    {
        public void DoSomething(Message m)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(m != null);
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Name));
            // Do Something           
        }
    }
}
```

In Main i get the following Warning CodeContracts: requires unproven: !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Name)

Any idea how to fix it?

If I change main to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IService s = new Service();

    Message messagesCreatorTestMessage = MessagesCreator.TestMessage;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messagesCreatorTestMessage.Name))
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    s.sendMessage(messagesCreatorTestMessage);
}
```

the warning disappears, but there should be other more elegant ways of doing this.

Comment: Also, you need to activate full static checking for code contracts

Answer (score 3):

The `Ensures` in the `Message` constructor only specifies that the condition will be true when the constructor finishes; it does not indicate that the condition will be true for the life of the `Message` instance.

To do this, use the [Contract.Invariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412890.aspx) method:

```
class Message
{
    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void MessageInvariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name));
    }

    public Message(string _name)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name));
        Contract.Ensures(this.Name == _name);
        this.Name = _name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this is the problem:

```
// In the Message constructor
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_componentName));
```

I suspect you mean:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name));
```

It's not clear to me where `_componentName` even comes from...

Comment: @Bogdan: If you were typing out your code, then it's clearly not the same code which actually gave you the error. It's also incomplete - there's no Service class, for example. Please give a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.